# What is the scriptural source of the Banalinga Kavacham?

Tags: shiva, reference-request, kavacha

The [Banalinga Kavacham](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/bANalingakavacha.html) is as follows:

> बाणलिङ्गकवचम्
>
> अस्य बाणलिङ्ग कवचस्य संहारभैरवऋषिर्गायत्रीच्छन्दः,
> हौं बीजं, हूं शक्तिः, नमः कीलकं, श्रीबाणलिङ्ग सदाशिवो देवता,
> ममाभीष्ट सिद्ध्यर्थं जपे विनियोगः ॥
>
> ॐ कारो मे शिरः पातु नमः पातु ललाटकम् ।
> शिवस्य कण्ठदेशं मे वक्षोदेशं षडक्षरम् ॥ १॥
>
> बाणेश्वरः कटीं पातु द्वावूरू चन्द्रशेखरः ।
> पादौ विश्वेश्वरः साक्षात् सर्वाङ्गं लिङ्गरूपधृक् ॥ २॥
>
> इतिदं कवचं पूर्व्वं बाणलिङ्गस्य कान्ते
> पठति यदि मनुष्यः प्राञ्जलिः शुद्धचित्तः ।
> व्रजति शिवसमीपं रोगोशोकप्रमुक्तो
> बहुधनसुखभोगी बाणलिङ्ग प्रसादतः ॥ ३॥
>
> इति बाणलिङ्ग कवचं समाप्तम् ॥

Which scripture is it from?